# Angular NgrxStore dispatch Action inside Selector Called many times

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

im working on Angular project with ngRx store (first time i use it) , i want to to dispatch Action to Get users courses when i get my user from the Store , but the action is Called many times. this is my Code :

```
// method called in the NgOnInit
loadUserCourses() {

    this.store.select(getCurrentUserSelector).subscribe((user: UserDTO) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('dispatch(SearchCoursesByUserIdAction');
        this.store.dispatch(SearchCoursesByUserIdAction({ userId: user.id }));
      }
    });
}
```

when i check my console i found that the console msg is printed 5 or 6 times even in the network tab i found that  there are multiple http Calls.
do you have any idea what the problem in my code what's the best practise to dispatch my `SearchCoursesByUserIdAction`

Comment: This violates the NgRx best practices on so many levels. To avoid such issues with multiple calls, either dispatch the action where you subscribe to the selector, or if possible, dispatch it from the effect.

Comment: @mat.hudak "either dispatch the action where you subscribe to the selector" this is what i did no ?

Comment: Sorry, I was bit focused on my issue and didn't realize it. I'll post the suggested solution in the answer

Answer (score -1):

Generally, when subscribing to selectors and dispatching the actions from them it's good to make sure that you'll react only in specific condition, i.e. unique data. Otherwise it's quite simple to end up in the endless loop.

So either `take` only first change, or use [distinctUntilChanged](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) operators

```typescript
this.store.select(getCurrentUserSelector)
.pipe(
  // take(1) or first() - if you are interested only in one change
  distinctUntilChanged() // react only if the current user has changed
)
.subscribe((user: UserDTO) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('dispatch(SearchCoursesByUserIdAction');
    this.store.dispatch(SearchCoursesByUserIdAction({ userId: user.id }));
  }
});
```

But I would still check your reducers and used action to make sure, that there are no unnecessary updates to the user store, which make this selector to react.